# Identify duplicate records in python dataframe based on groupby concept, skipping first 2 occurences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

My requirement is to identify duplicate elements/occurrences for the same store,

- if only 1 incident is present for a particular store and category -> mark 1st as 'False' (skip it)
- if 2 incidents are present for the same element -> mark 1st and 2nd as 'False' & copy 1st incident number
- if 3 same elements present, mark 1st & 2nd as 'False' and mark 3rd as 'True' & copy 1st incident number
- if 4 or more same elements present, mark 1st & 2nd as 'False' and rest all as 'True'  & copy 1st incident number
  I have following dataframe:

```
dct = { 'inc_num' :[101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113],
        'store' : ['A','A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C','C'],
        'part1' : ['oil','oil', 'filter', 'oil', 'oil', 'filter', 'oil','filter', 'filter', 'wiper', 'oil', 'oil', 'oil'],
       }


sample= pd.DataFrame(dct)

print (sample)

    inc_num store   part1
0   101        A    oil
1   102        A    oil
2   103        A    filter
3   104        A    oil
4   105        A    oil
5   106        B    filter
6   107        B    oil
7   108        B    filter
8   109        B    filter
9   110        C    wiper
10  111        C    oil
11  112        C    oil
12  113        C    oil
```

My expected dataframe is :

```
    inc_num store   part1    Duplicate    Source_Inc_Num
0   101        A    oil       False       101     # Ignore 1st occurrence; but 3rd occurrence is present; flag=False; 
1   102        A    oil       False       101     # Ignore 2nd occurrence; but 3rd occurrence is present; flag = False; copy 1st incident num
2   103        A    filter    False       NaN
3   104        A    oil       True        101 # For Store A 'oil' repeated 3rd time; flag = True; copy 1st incident num
4   105        A    oil       True        101 # For Store A 'oil' repeated 4th time;flag = True; copy 1st incident num
5   106        B    filter    False       106     # Ignore 1st occurrence; flag=False;
6   107        B    oil       False       NaN
7   108        B    filter    False       106 # For Store B 'filter' repeated 2nd time;but 3rd occurrence is present; flag = True; copy 1st incident num
8   109        B    filter    True        106 # For Store B 'filter' repeated 3rd time;flag = True; copy 1st incident num
9   110        C    wiper     False       NaN
10  111        C    oil       False       111     # Ignore 1st occurrence; flag=False;
11  112        C    oil       False       111 # For Store C 'oil' repeated 2nd time; but 3rd occurrence is present; flag = True; copy 1st incident num
12  113        C    oil       True        111 # For Store C 'oil' repeated 3rd time; flag = True; copy 1st incident num
```

I understand using `pandas.duplicated(subset=['store','part1'])` requirement can be achieved however can not skip the first 2 occurrences. Any suggestion?

Please do ask for any queries/clarification.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

```
groups = sample.groupby(['store','part1'])
sizes = groups['store'].transform('size')
orders = groups.cumcount()
first_rows = groups['inc_num'].transform('first')

sample['Duplicate'] = orders > 1
sample['Source_Inc_Num'] = np.where(sizes==1, np.nan, first_rows)
```

Output:

```
    inc_num store   part1  Duplicate  Source_Inc_Num
0       101     A     oil      False           101.0
1       102     A     oil      False           101.0
2       103     A  filter      False             NaN
3       104     A     oil       True           101.0
4       105     A     oil       True           101.0
5       106     B  filter      False           106.0
6       107     B     oil      False             NaN
7       108     B  filter      False           106.0
8       109     B  filter       True           106.0
9       110     C   wiper      False             NaN
10      111     C     oil      False           111.0
11      112     C     oil      False           111.0
12      113     C     oil       True           111.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not everything has a clever API.  You're going to need to write a function to loop through the entries one by one.  Keep a dict with store names and number of entries, and just insert the new column value by hand.